# How to match a string against multiple regex?

Tags: python, regex, string

At the moment I am using the below filter to increment elements in arr, given a list of strings as an argument, is there an efficient way to do this in python.I got millions of such lists to validate upon.

```
  def countbycat(tempfilter):
        arr=[0,0,0,0,0]
        apattern,dpattern,mpattern,upattern,tpattern = re.compile("^[a]--*"),re.compile("^[d]--*"),re.compile("^[m]--*"),re.compile("^[u]--*"),re.compile("^[t]--*")
        for each in tempfilter:
            if upattern.match(each):
                 arr[0]+=1
            elif mpattern.match(each):
                 arr[1]+=1
            elif dpattern.match(each):
                 arr[2]=1
            elif apattern.match(each):
                 arr[3]+=1
            elif tpattern.match(each):
                 arr[4]+=1
        return arr
```

Comment: If you have millions of strings but only five regexes, you question should be "match multiple strings to a regex", not visa versa.

Comment: You shouldn't use regex for this in the first place. It's not needed. Regular string comparisons and lookups give the same functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the regular expressions given in the question, you can use following regular expression using character class:

```
[admut]-
```

- `[admut]` will match any of `a`, `d`, `m`, `u`, `t`
- `^` can be omitted because `re.match` matches only at the beginning of the string.
- removed `-*` because it's pointless; only one `-` is enough to check `-` appear after the `a/d/m/u/t`.

And instead of using array, you can use a dictionary; no need to remember indexes:

```
def countbycat(tempfilter):
    count = dict.fromkeys('admut', 0)
    pattern = re.compile("[admut]-")
    for each in tempfilter:
        if pattern.match(each):
            count[each[0]] += 1
    return count
```

Instead of [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys), you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: @StefanPochmann, I used `-+` instead of `--*` because it's shorter and more expressive than the other: Both will match one or more `-`.  (`--*`: match `-` and 0 or more `-`), (`-+`: match 1 or more `-`); both matches same things.

Comment: I think you can safely remove the `+`. It doesn't do anything good here and only slows things down. And since this question is about efficiency...

Comment: @StefanPochmann, I got your point. I updated the answer to remove `+`. Thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: You can make it a bit faster by using `match = re.compile("[admut]-").match` and then `if match(each):`. I tested `timeit(lambda: pattern.match(each))` and `timeit(lambda: match(each))` and the latter was about 10% faster for the words I tested.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regex for this. You are checking for a very specific, fixed condition. Namely, `each[1] == '-'`  and `each[0] in 'admut'`. Both of these are *much* faster than regex. The later can also be used as a mapping.

```
def countbycat(tempfilter):
  arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  char_idx = {  # map admit to indices
    'u': 0,
    'm': 1,
    'd': 2,
    'a': 3,
    't': 4,
    }
  for each in tempfilter:
    if each[1] == '-':  # detect trailing -
      try:
        arr[char_idx[each[0]]] += 1  # increment position pointed to by admut
      except KeyError:  # each[0] not any of admut
        pass
  return arr
```

Comment: `each[1]` will raise `IndexError` if a `len(each) <= 1`. `each[0]` .. same for empty string.

Comment: @falstrue It will also raise `TypeError` if `each` is an integer. oO I'm assuming all of the possibly infinite cases of required input sanitization are performed.

Comment: @StefanPochmann `each[1] == "-"` takes 0.0639 usec, `char_idx[each[0]]` takes 0.0672 usec, `pat.match(each)` (from `re.compile`) takes 1.41 usec. So, roughly 10 times faster. Tested with python3.4.3.

Comment: If strings with length less than 2 are a concern, you can add check `len(each) > 2`.

Answer (score 1):

In your simple case, go for [falsetru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38161411/3821804)

In general case, you can combine your patterns into one regex (provided that your regexes doesn't contain capturing groups), and check which wart of regex matched:

```
patterns = ["^[a]-+", "^[d]-+", "^[m]-+", "^[u]-+", "^[t]-+"]

complex_pattern = re.compile('|'.join(['(%s)' % i for i in patterns]))

# imperative way

arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

for each in tempfilter:
    match = complex_pattern.match(each)
    if match:
        arr[match.lastgroup + 1] += 1

return arr

# functional way

from collections import Counter

matches_or_none = (complex_pattern.match(each) for each in tempfilter)

return Counter(match.lastgroup + 1 for match in matches_or_none if match is not None)
```

Comment: For this simple case, there's no need to use regex at all. ;)

Comment: Appreciate you providing the actual answer to OP's question here even if it's not the optimal approach to solving the problem, thanks